# Generic Class with where clause

Tags: c#, generics

I did search the web and have some examples on using where clause when creating a generic class.Most of them showcased less real world usage.

Will someone be able to point out to some decent examples.

Comment: Plenty of examples here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx

Comment: Maybe http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx

Comment: Here is one of mine I consider particularly indecent: `public interface IDevicePlotData<T, U> where T: IDeviceDataSet<U> where U:IDataPoint`

Comment: I can't believe this question is google hit #3 right now on the perfectly reasonable query "c# generic method where clause".  Can it be deleted or something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A real-world usage could be when you want to use a particular type deriving from an interface (for instance), without creating the instance yourself.

Example:

```
class FooReader<T> where T : IFoo, new()
{
    public int Read()
    {
        var foo = new T();
        return foo.Read();
    }
}

class Foo : IFoo
{
    public int Read()
    {
        return 42;
    }
}

interface IFoo
{
    int Read();
}
```

Usage:

```
var reader = new FooReader<Foo>();
var result = reader.Read();
```